# sharp architecture problem

Tags: s#arp-architecture

I started to use the latest s#arp architecture (1.9.5.0). I sometimes add some data to the db via a console application using something like this:

```
Repository<OriginalSequence> SequenceRepository = new Repository<OriginalSequence>();
...
SequenceRepository.SaveOrUpdate(Sequence);
SequenceRepository.DbContext.CommitChanges();

NHibernateSession.Current.Flush();
NHibernateSession.Current.Clear();
```

Unfortunately, I get:

ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.Data.NHibernate.ISessionFactoryKeyProvider

This has to do with DI I think. which is usually only necessary when I use it in a web app or has something fundamentally changed? Thanks.

Christian

PS:

Please note that I start off with:

```
string[] mappingAssemblies = new string[] { "Bla.Data" };
                string configFile = "NHibernate.config";
                NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration config = NHibernateSession.Init(
                        new SimpleSessionStorage(),
                        mappingAssemblies,
                        new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
                        configFile);
```

This used to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the 1.9.6 release, but you need to register the default implementation of ISessionFactoryKeyProvider in the Windsor container.

In ComponentRegistrar.cs in the CastleWindsor folder of the "Web" project add this code to the AddGenericRepositoriesTo method:

```
container.Register(
  Component
    .For(typeof(ISessionFactoryKeyProvider))
    .ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
    .Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I saw a similar post somewhere else. Everything is already there. Please note that I use things in a console app which used to work fine. I don't think this stuff will ever be invoked ...

Comment: This was a change introduced in 1.9.5, DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider now needs to be registered in the Windsor container for it to work. You ought to be doing this anyway for other components e.g. IEntityDuplicateChecker, IValidator.

Comment: In a console app you will have to explicity call
`ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo` and pass in a Windsor container,
you should also initialise the ServiceLocator with: `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new
WindsorServiceLocator(container));`

In a web app this is done in MvcApplication.Application_Start in
Global.asax.cs, but you will have to add it to the start up code of
your console app.