# Sharp architecture 2.0 unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

I am just trying to test some validation which involves the database. The setup of my test code looks something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UserValidatorTester : RepositoryTestsBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        ServiceLocatorInitializer.Init();
        base.SetUp(); 
    }


...
```

The ServiceLocatorInitializer looks like this:

```
    public class ServiceLocatorInitializer
        {
            public static void Init() 
            {
                IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

                container.Register(
                        Component
                            .For(typeof(IEntityDuplicateChecker))
                            .ImplementedBy(typeof(EntityDuplicateChecker))
                            .Named("entityDuplicateChecker"));

container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ISessionFactoryKeyProvider)).ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider)).Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));


                ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(container));
            }
        }
```

I am getting:

```
at SharpArch.Domain.SafeServiceLocator`1.GetService()
```

at SharpArch.NHibernate.SessionFactoryKeyHelper.GetKeyFrom(Object anObject)
at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.get_Session()
at EID2.Tasks.Repositories.UserRepository.SaveOrUpdate(User entity) in C:\Users\csetzkorn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EID2\Solutions\EID2.Tasks\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:line 17
at EID2.Tasks.UserTasks.CreateUser(CreateUserViewModel CreateUserViewModel) in C:\Users\csetzkorn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EID2\Solutions\EID2.Tasks\UserTasks.cs:line 33
at EID2.Tests.Validation.UserValidatorTester.LoadTestData() in C:\Users\csetzkorn\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\EID2\Solutions\EID2.Tests\Validation\UserValidatorTester.cs:line 39
at SharpArch.Testing.NUnit.NHibernate.RepositoryTestsBase.SetUp()
--NullReferenceException
at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.get_Current()
at SharpArch.Domain.SafeServiceLocator`1.GetService()

Christian

PS:

Included dlls:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Castle.Core">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\Castle.Core.2.5.2\lib\SL4\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Castle.Windsor">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\Castle.Windsor.2.5.3\lib\NET40\Castle.Windsor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter.1.0\lib\NET35\CommonServiceLocator.WindsorAdapter.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EID2.Tasks">
      <HintPath>..\xxx.Tasks\bin\Debug\xxx.Tasks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FluentValidation, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a82054b837897c66, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\FluentValidation\FluentValidation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.0\lib\NET35\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MvcContrib.TestHelper">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci.3.0.68.0\lib\MvcContrib.TestHelper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NHibernate, Version=3.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\NHibernate\NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\NHibernate\NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NHibernate.Validator">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\NHibernate\NHibernate.Validator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\NUnit.2.5.10.11092\lib\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Rhino.Mocks">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\RhinoMocks\Rhino.Mocks.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpArch.Domain">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\SharpArchitecture\SharpArch.Domain.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpArch.NHibernate">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\SharpArchitecture\SharpArch.NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpArch.Testing">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\SharpArchitecture\SharpArch.Testing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpArch.Testing.NUnit">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\SharpArchitecture\SharpArch.Testing.NUnit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SharpArch.Tests">
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\SharpArchitecture\SharpArch.Tests.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
      <HintPath>..\..\Packages\System.Data.SQLite.1.0.66.0\lib\System.Data.SQLite.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\ReferencedAssemblies\ASP.NET MVC\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

PPS:

sql lite config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;</property>
        <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Make sure you have included the nhibernate configuration to your unit test project.

Comment: This is def. included for sql lite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a couple of the things that could go wrong with sqlite and there are different solutions for different problems, I think the problem you having is because sqlite.dll was built against .net System.Data while what you have is .net 4 System.Data, try adding:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

to the configuration element in the test app.config.

Also, if you are on x64 machine, and are referencing the x86 sqlite, then you need to change the target framework for your test assembly to x86 (right click project, select properties, build tab, and select x86 for the target framework)

Comment: Thanks. Getting there but obtain this now: ServiceLocator has not been initialized; I was trying to retrieve SharpArch.NHibernate.ISessionFactoryKeyProvider
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at SharpArch.Domain.SafeServiceLocator`1.GetService()
 at SharpArch.NHibernate.SessionFactoryKeyHelper.GetKeyFrom(Object anObject)
 at SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId`2.get_Session() etc.

Comment: You need to make sure that the DefaultSessionKeyProvider has been registered with Windsor, make sure you have this in your ComponentRegistrar:


    `container.Register(
        Component.For(typeof(ISessionFactoryKeyProvider))
        .ImplementedBy(typeof(DefaultSessionFactoryKeyProvider))
        .Named("sessionFactoryKeyProvider"));`

Comment: Or look at the answer from one of your previous questions:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119444/sharp-architecture-problem/5119696#5119696)

Comment: Thanks chrisr I have added this and get the error shown in the question (I have edited the question).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the NHibernate Session factory cannot be created. Read the error message:

```
 System.ArgumentException : Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

Do you have the SQLLite dll included in your project?

> System.Data.SQLite.dll

Comment: Could it be that NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver is for .net 2.0 and I am working with 4.0 or something like this?

Comment: Odd - could you list all the files in your Unit Testing Project's Bin folder (except for your own custom dlls of course).